# How to browse files of a node.js server from a browser (using p5.js)

Tags: node.js, p5.js

Everything is said in the Title. Any idea would be very appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: This is a really broad question and P5.js is completely unrelated to what you're asking (unless I totally misinterpreted it?).

Comment: https://github.com/indexzero/http-server can work as a static file server, that you could browse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use express, define static resources and use [serve-index](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index).

Comment: Glad to hear that. There are more modules out there.
Don't forget to mark the question if ti works for you.